# how do you get the following summation.

Tags: summation

$\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}(1-x)^r}{r}$

I tried it using  $\binom{n}{r}$ = $\binom{n-1}{r}$+$\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ but I am not getting the desired result.

given answer is $\frac{1-x}{1}$+$\frac{1-x^2}{2}$ $\frac{1-x^3}{3}$+......+$\frac{1-x^n}{n}$

Comment: does the question begin from r=0 or 1?

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.